# Ionic upload multiple videos using one http request

Tags: php, angular, api, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an Ionic 3 app that is supposed to upload 5 videos at once to my PHP API.

Currently, I can send only one video with Ionic's Http Plugin. How can I upload all videos at once?

```
  let body = new FormData();

  body.append('file1', this.favorites[0]);
  body.append('file2', this.favorites[1]);
  body.append('file3', this.favorites[2]);
  body.append('file4', this.favorites[3]);
  body.append('file5', this.favorites[4]);

  this.http
  .uploadFile(this.apiLink+"user/upload",body,{},"","")
  .then(data => {   
    // Do something
  })
  .catch(error => {
  // Catch error
  });}
```

Here is my PHP code

```
//Upload file
$app->post("/user/upload", function (Request $request) use ($app) { 

$file1 = $request->files->get('file1');
$file2 = $request->files->get('file2');
$file3 = $request->files->get('file3');
$file4 = $request->files->get('file4');
$file5 = $request->files->get('file5');

$files = [];

array_push($files,$file1);
array_push($files,$file2);
array_push($files,$file3);
array_push($files,$file4);
array_push($files,$file5);

$rsp = upload($files);

return $app->json(array('response'=>sizeof($files)));

});
```

Comment: code please..........

Comment: Not possible with Single HTTP request. You need to make 5 requests to upload 5 videos. These requests can be parallel or one after another.

Comment: @RakeshBurbure Please see the code i added

Comment: @AtulSharma how can i catch them in my api and know that they belong to the same request? because each user can upload 5 videos and api generates and returns one compiled video